# AspxGridview Add new row and retain last row value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a aspxgridview that will allow the user to add new row. What I want to do is to retain the value of last row everytime the new row has been added. I have the Add new row button outside the gridview. Is it possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is what I have so far.

**Front-end**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="true"  
                    ClientInstanceName="sampleGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="forFromGrid" Theme="Material" Font-Size="11px" KeyFieldName="thisid" 
                    Width="100%" CssClass="body" 
                        OnHtmlFooterCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlFooterCellPrepared" >
                    <SettingsBehavior ColumnResizeMode="NextColumn" />
                    <Settings VerticalScrollBarMode="Visible" VerticalScrollableHeight="345"  />
                    <settingscommandbutton>
                        <showadaptivedetailbutton buttontype="Image">
                        </showadaptivedetailbutton>
                        <hideadaptivedetailbutton buttontype="Image">
                        </hideadaptivedetailbutton>
                    </settingscommandbutton>
                    <SettingsDataSecurity AllowEdit="False" AllowInsert="False" />

                    <Columns>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="thisid" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" 
                            VisibleIndex="0" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false">
                        <SettingsHeaderFilter>
                        <DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
                        </SettingsHeaderFilter>
                        <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="no." Visible="false" 
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1">

                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="product"  visible="false"
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2">
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="product id" Caption="Product"
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3">
                     <DataItemTemplate>
                            <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmdProduct" runat="server" DataSourceID="Product" ValueType="System.String" 
                            ValueField="p_pcode" TextField="p_pname" OnInit="cmbProduct_Init" Width="100%" Theme="Material" 
                            IncrementalFilteringDelay="600" CallbackPageSize="20" EnableCallbackMode="true" DropDownStyle="DropDown">
                                <Border BorderStyle="None" />
                            </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Product" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BMS %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [code], [name] FROM [product] WHERE ([status] = @stat) order by [name] asc ">
                            <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="A" Name="stat" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="variation" visible="false" 
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4">

                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="varid" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" Caption="Version"
                        VisibleIndex="5">
                       <DataItemTemplate>
                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID = "cmbVariant" runat="server" DataSourceID="Variation" ValueType="System.String" 
                        ValueField="v_matid" TextField="v_var" OnInit="cmbVar_Init" Width="100%" Theme="Material" 
                        IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains" IncrementalFilteringDelay="600" CallbackPageSize="20" 
                        EnableCallbackMode="true" DropDownStyle="DropDown">
                            <Border BorderStyle="None" />
                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Var" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BMS %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [varid], [varcode], [var] FROM [variant] WHERE (([varcode] = @varcode) AND ([varstat] = @varstat))">
                        <SelectParameters>  
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="varcode" DefaultValue="" SessionField="varid" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="A" Name="varstat" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                     </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>


                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="place" visible="false"
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="8">

                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="placeid" Caption="Program"
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="9">
                     <DataItemTemplate>
                             <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbPlace" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" DataSourceID="Place" Theme="Material"
                             ValueField = "pg_place" TextField="pg_plcname" Width="100%" CssClass="EditDropdown" OnInit="cmbPlace_Init" 
                             IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains" IncrementalFilteringDelay="600" CallbackPageSize="20" 
                             EnableCallbackMode="true" DropDownStyle="DropDown">
                                <Border BorderStyle="None" />
                             </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Place" runat="server" 
                             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BMS %>" 
                             SelectCommand="SELECT [pg_plccode], [pg_plcname] FROM [place] WHERE ([stat] = @stat) order by pg_plcname asc">
                             <SelectParameters>
                             <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="A" Name="pg_stat" Type="String" />
                             </SelectParameters>
                             </asp:SqlDataSource>
                         </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>





                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="cost" Caption="Internal Cost"
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="12">
                       <DataItemTemplate>
                                        <dx:ASPxSpinEdit ID="acost" DecimalPlaces="2" DisplayFormatString="N" OnInit="IntCost_Init" Width="100%" Theme="Material" 
                                        CssClass="EditDropdown" runat="server" Number=" 0" SpinButtons-ClientVisible="false" AllowMouseWheel="false" HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                            <Border BorderStyle="None" />
                                        </dx:ASPxSpinEdit>
                                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="chnfr_rkey" visible="false"
                        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="13">

                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    </Columns>
                      <StylesPager Button-HorizontalAlign="Right" Button-HoverStyle-BackgroundImage-HorizontalPosition="right"></StylesPager>
                    <Templates>
                        <PagerBar>
                        <table width="100%" class="tablebutton_change">
                            <tr style="float:right;">

                            <td class = "btn_setting">
                            <dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_addnew"  runat="server"  Text="Add new row" Theme="Mulberry" CssClass="btn_change"
                            AutoPostBack="true" Image-Url="~/images/icons/addnewrow.png" CausesValidation="false" 
                            UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="AddnewClick">
                            </dx:ASPxButton>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>

                        </PagerBar>
                    </Templates>
                    <settingspager AlwaysShowPager="true">
                    </settingspager>

                    <SettingsBehavior ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="True" />
                    <Styles Header-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <header horizontalalign="Center">
                        </header>
                    </Styles>


                    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Back-end**

```
Protected Sub AddnewClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sales").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "insert"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idno", Session("idno").ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variant", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varid", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@palce", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@palceid", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Date.Today)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        forFromGrid.SelectParameters(0).DefaultValue = Session("idno").ToString
        fordtl.SelectParameters(0).DefaultValue = Session("idno").ToString
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the status of your code? like, How its working ?, did you getting any error ?. BTW, do you want to retain the values of very last row of the grid or very first row?

Comment: @Kavin It is working fine. But when I enter add new row supply a value and clicked again the add new row button the value that I entered on the first row is empty you have to enter it again.

Comment: Your code Confusing me, Why you have the two Add new button ?

Comment: @Kavin sorry pasted it wrong. I update my codes.

Comment: ok. How you made/show the new empty row, Is it by using INLINE EDIT

Comment: @Kavin no. Im pooping it up by using my code behind code. Im actually a newbie in devexpress that's why my work is a trash. Hehe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150566/discussion-between-kavin-and-xtian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
You should Create the empty(Add New) row from client side instead of creating from server side. change the button code in front end like following,

```
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_addnew" runat="server" Text="Add new row"
    Theme="Mulberry" CssClass="btn_change" AutoPostBack="false" 
Image-Url="~/images/icons/addnewrow.png" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"> 
        <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { 
        sampleGrid.AddNewRow(); 
        }" /> 
        </dx:ASPxButton>
```

https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientGridView.AddNewRow.method -- here explained how we can call the server side events dynamically from client side. instead of use the grid command button column option or default button.

And as per our chat discussion,

It seems you are trying batch update. You can do batch update by two ways. 1. Individually (CRUD) 2. at once (Batch update).

**1. Individually (CRUD - ASPxGridView RowInserting/RowUpdating/RowDeleting events)** Use If you want to submit a batch of modifications individually I.e. ASPxGridView RowInserting/RowUpdating/RowDeleting events

**2. At once (Batch update - ASPxGridView.BatchUpdate event):** Use If you want to submit a batch of modifications at once ( ASPxGridView.BatchUpdate event)

Both the above procedures are clearly explained [here](http://ASPxGridView.BatchUpdate%20event)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Im actually working on two gridview. Sorry forgot to include that on my question. Im about to create a new question. The two gridview is synchronize every time you add a new row both of gridview should insert a new row.

Comment: For that also solution is there, you should think about in different ways. Just initiate the add new row function for second grid also in that button client side click event. like,
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { 
        sampleGrid.AddNewRow(); 
        sampleGrid2.AddNewRow(); 
        }" />

Comment: Have added a new question. Would you mind to view it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411500/two-aspxgridview-synchronize-inserting-of-new-row Thank you!

Comment: I already seen your new post. But, From my above solution , Just one line is enough to add new row for both grid. Its ridiculous, why are u creating new post. You should not create the new row from server side. your way is very wrong. after enter the values only you should insert the rows into data base.

Comment: Not its not adding try it out. It keeps on loading.

Comment: check the ClientInstanceName is correct are not. which means, Grid ClientInstanceName.AddNewRow();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150585/discussion-between-kavin-and-xtian).